# Modify elements get from AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a Paragraph gets from angularjs by using

```
<p>{literal}<p ng-bind-html="toTrust(article._data.abstract)"></p>{/literal}</p>
```

the result would be an example like

```
Introduction aaaaaaaaaa, Methods bbbbbb
```

I want to modify it, to make Introduction in one line, and the methods in the other line like

```
Introduction aaaaaa
Methods bbbbbb
```

I tried add a script below it to do this, but AngularJs seems not load it correctly.

actually, i am very new to angular, and the idea I tried was using jQuery to find this paragraph and pass into a regular expression function to rewrite the whole paragraph
but since the paragraph input directly from the angular ng-bind-html. so I have no idea how to pass it into a regular expression function

I dont know whats the other ways to do it?

Comment: Your paragraphs are nested, which is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a filter to replace commas with new lines.

Something like:

```
App.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function(text) {
        return text.replace(',', '<br/>');
    }
})
```

Should be able to implement it like this:

```
<p>{literal}<p ng-bind-html="toTrust(article._data.abstract) | myFilter"></p>{/literal}</p>
```

Have not tested it though!

Comment: @slepber, as long as the "Introduction" or nothing else contains a comma, you may want to instead look for `, Methods` and replace with `<br>Methods`

Comment: the example is more complicate than this, the there are lots of text also inlcuded ","  between introduction and Methods. But I think I already got the idea which is to write a filter fucntion. and I will use regular expression to parse.  and thank you for ur help~ @smerny